# C# Regex based date parsing and extraction

Tags: c#, regex, parsing, datetime

my question is pretty simple: I need to extract the first date from the following input:

```
# 12/29/2014 00:00 - 1/5/2015 00:00
```

Now, I've implemented this method using a list of regex found thru the internet which, I think, are right to parse a datetime value:

```
string datePattern = @"^(((((((0?[13578])|(1[02]))[\.\-/]?((0?[1-9])|([12]\d)|(3[01])))|(((0?[469])|(11))[\.\-/]?((0?[1-9])|([12]\d)|(30)))|((0?2)[\.\-/]?((0?[1-9])|(1\d)|(2[0-8]))))[\.\-/]?(((19)|(20))?([\d][\d]))))|((0?2)[\.\-/]?(29)[\.\-/]?(((19)|(20))?(([02468][048])|([13579][26])))))$";

private string extractDate(string line) {
       return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(line, datePattern, RegexOptions.CultureInvariant).Value.Trim(); 
}
```

I think that the `Match.Value` is a property referred to the *first* occurrence of the string matched by the parser of the Regex class.
But it returns a null string.

Could you kindly help me in that simple kind of problem?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any non-date text in the file which can be in this format?

Comment: Is your input *always* a string of that form? Because if so you can do this with a `Substring`.

Comment: To be more precise: I need the date only parsed in european format i.e.: dd/MM/yyyy. I have to omit the following time.

Comment: Your date is in MM/dd/yyyy format right now

Comment: Yes, the problem is that the day does not always start with two numbers.

Comment: Remove anchors and try

Comment: Your dates are in the US format

Comment: You could simply split by the `-` and then use the following pattern: `MM/dd/yyyy` to parse the string as a date time object.

Answer (score 2):

You simply can use a [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) method after the [Splitting your string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx):

```
var stringToParse = "# 12/29/2014 00:00 - 1/5/2015 00:00";
var splitValues = stringToParse.Split('-');
var firstSplitted = splitValues[0].Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var neededDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(firstSplitted[1], "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: I think OP is worried that the input might be `M/d` rather than `MM/dd`. If not, you can just use `Substring(2, 10)` rather than those splits :)

Comment: @Rawling He can even provide the string with time, and use `.Date` property of the resulted DateTime

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to everyone.
Basing on the kind suggestion of VMAtm I've made this HORRIBLE solution to that stupid problem which just took me a lot of time.
I've splitted the date into year, month and date, than I return a new DateTime formatted in "MM/dd/yyyy" (and not dd/MM/yyyy as stated befor).

Excuse me if you are horrified by this solution but it seems to work fine even if with just one digit for the Month.

```
private string extractDate(string line)
        {
            var splitValues = line.Split('-');
            var firstSplitted = splitValues[0].Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            var dateSplitted = firstSplitted[1].Split(new char[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            return new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(dateSplitted[2]), Convert.ToInt32(dateSplitted[1]), Convert.ToInt32(dateSplitted[0])).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"); 
        }
```

Any other and more elegant solution is very accepted.
Thanks again to everyone.

Comment: Why don't you return firstSplitted[1] if you need just a string representation?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clearly understand: is string starts with "# " or digit.
In any case general pattern are:

```
    private static string extractDate(string line)
    {
        string datePattern = @"(?<=# |^)\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{1,4} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}";
        return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(line, datePattern, RegexOptions.CultureInvariant).Value.Trim();
    }
```

Main method for console testing:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var testLines = new List<string> { 
        @"# 12/29/2014 00:00 - 1/5/2015 00:00",
        @"12/29/2014 00:00 - 1/5/2015 00:00",
        @"2/9/14 00:00 - 1/5/2015 00:00",
        @"# 2/9/14 00:9 - 1/5/2015 00:00"
    };

    testLines.ForEach(t => Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} -> {1}", t, extractDate(t))));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in order to get both date :

```
        string input = "12/29/2014 00:00 - 1/5/2015 00:00";
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<month>(1[0-2]|0\d|\d))/(?<day>(3[0-1]|[0-2]\d|\d))/(?<year>[1-2]\d{3})\s(?<hour>(2[0-3]|[0-1]\d)):(?<min>[0-5]\d)");
        MatchCollection match = regex.Matches(input);

        foreach (Match m in match)
        {
       string year = m.Groups["year"].Value;
       string month = m.Groups["month"].Value;
       string day = m.Groups["day"].Value;
       string hour = m.Groups["hour"].Value;
       string min = m.Groups["min"].Value;

       Trace.WriteLine(m.Groups["year"].Value);
       Trace.WriteLine(m.Groups["month"].Value);
       Trace.WriteLine(m.Groups["day"].Value);
       Trace.WriteLine(m.Groups["hour"].Value);
       Trace.WriteLine(m.Groups["min"].Value);
        }
```